# Append a No Redirect to Iframe src using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following

```
 <iframe src="http://website.com:352/pictures/1">
```

How would I append a No Redirect such as upon visiting

```
"http://website.com:352/pictures/1?noRedirect"
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the `iframe` and `id` so you can get a handle on it, also change `src` to `data-src` on the initial DOM so that non redirect is not automatically loaded.

```
<iframe id="myIframe" data-src="http://website.com:352/pictures/1">
```

The you can add the no redirect param on load

```
jQuery(function() {
  var $iframe = $("#myIframe");
  var src = $iframe.attr('data-src');
  $iframe.attr('src', src + "?noRedirect");
});
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work. When I check the src of the iframe, it is the original, not the appended version.